# Elasticsearch search results filtering

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and I am using REST API for PHP to play around with data returned. I am using following code to retrieve data.

```
$params = [
        'index' => 'my_search',
        'type' => 'mytype',
        'from' => 0,
        'size' => 10,
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'must' => [
                        [ 'match' => [ 'validated' => true ] ],
                        [ 'match' => [ 'image' => true ] ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'sort' => [
                'created_at' => [ 'order' => 'asc']
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Above code returns data perfectly matching "validated=>true" and "image=>true".

Further I want to add open text search like we use /_search/?q=Apple macbook. I have tried to use match, multi_match, query_string options, but couldn't get success.

So, I want to retrieve results from ES that have "validated=>true", "image=>true" and matches with text "Apple macbook".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your document structure and which field "Apple macbook" text will be stored in the document

Comment: There are multiple fields. I have already used the query string results fetching using _search/?q=Apple macbook. Now in this way I don't have to provide any specific field of my ES document. The same way I want to adopt using PHP REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) or [simple_query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html)

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'my_search',
    'type' => 'mytype',
    'from' => 0,
    'size' => 10,
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    [ 'match' => [ 'validated' => true ] ],
                    [ 'match' => [ 'image' => true ] ],
                    [ 'query_string' => [ 'query' => 'Apple macbook' ] ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'sort' => [
            'created_at' => [ 'order' => 'asc']
        ]
    ]
    ];



$params = [
    'index' => 'my_search',
    'type' => 'mytype',
    'from' => 0,
    'size' => 10,
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    [ 'match' => [ 'validated' => true ] ],
                    [ 'match' => [ 'image' => true ] ],
                    [ 'simple_query_string' => [ 'query' => 'Apple macbook' ] ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'sort' => [
            'created_at' => [ 'order' => 'asc']
        ]
    ]
    ];
```

Comment: Working perfectly! Thanks

Comment: Glad it helps you somehow. Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this by 
enabling all_field mapping for your index, you can do that by following the below URL 
 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html
and then use the below ES query:

```
$params = [
        'index' => 'my_search',
        'type' => 'mytype',
        'from' => 0,
        'size' => 10,
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'must' => [
                        [ 'match' => [ '_all' => 'Apple macbook' ] ],
                        [ 'match' => [ 'validated' => true ] ],
                        [ 'match' => [ 'image' => true ] ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'sort' => [
                'created_at' => [ 'order' => 'asc']
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Comment: Yes, I read about _all option earlier, but didn't work well. Tried your suggested solution, but in my case it is not returning any result. Thanks for your efforts.